# Unable to connect to MSSQL 2014 with Golang (without opening static port on MSSQL)

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, go, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to connect my Golang app to MSSQL 2014.

I have been successful using - https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb
For this, I only had enable a static port on my MSSQL & things were good, I was able to get data.

But what I want to achieve is to connect to MSSQL without needing to open up a static port on MSSQL, as my PHP app already does this using PDO.

I also tried using - https://github.com/minus5/gofreetds
but was unable to install FreeTDS on Windows. But even in that I was seeing somewhere to setup a port for MSSQL, so I stopped.

Another golang pkg that I came across was - https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc
But due to lack of doc, I'm still stuck. Unit tests for this pkg fail, saying the user login failed. But the login creds are working fine.

Has anyone been successful in achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

For a database port # always be there. Either default or user-defined. MSSQL default port # are 1433 for TCP/IP and 1434 for USD connection. `denisenkom/go-msmsqldb` driver already using default port # if you don't provide one.

`denisenkom/go-msmsqldb` driver supports three ways (ADO, ODBC, URL) of connection string format. Choose yours as documented here https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb#connection-parameters-and-dsn

Comment: Both 1433 & 1434 ports are disabled for MSSQL on my machine.. but still PHP app works fine with MSSQL. So, I was hoping I will be able to achieve the same with Go. **denisenkom/go-msmsqldb** pkg worked after I enabled 1433 for TCP/IP.  Isn't there anyway that it would be possible without a port. I'm not able to understand how my PHP app works. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: This is my PHP connection, that works even without the ports being enabled.

`$this->db = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=' . DATABASE_SERVER
                                 . ';Database=' . DATABASE_BNAME,
                                 DATABASE_LOGIN_NAME,
                                 DATABASE_PASSWORD
                                );`

Comment: Can you share connection string format use in go and value of `DATABASE_SERVER` and `DATABASE_BNAME`?